# Javascript singleton pattern initialized values are not getting in html file

Tags: javascript

I created a singleton pattern are shown below. I want to use this values in html file. So I created a js file with name as 'scoreboard.js' and include in index.html file. But I cant access this object value.

scoreboard.js

```
var scoreboard = function() {

        var message = 'Welcome to the game!';

        function printMessage() {

             console.log(message);

        }

        function updateMessage(newMessage) {

            message = newMessage;

        }

        //return an object that represents our new module

        return {

             showMessage: printMessage,

             updateMessage: updateMessage

        }

    }();
```

index.html

```
<script src="scoreboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
        scoreboard.printMessage();
        scoreboard.updateMessage("Let the game begin!");
</script>
```

I Am getting error as

```
TypeError: scoreboard.showMessages is not a function
```

Comment: The property of the object you returned was `showMessage`.

Comment: i.e. `scoreboard.showMessage()` will execute the `printMessage` function ... oh, and where did `myScoreboard` come from? it's `scoreboard` everywhere in the code

Comment: TypeError I updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the function with the same name you returned it :

```
showMessage: printMessage,
```

So call

```
scoreboard.showMessage();
```

---

Alternatively, just be consistant with you function naming, and replace

```
 showMessage: printMessage,
```

with

```
 printMessage: printMessage,
```

Comment: @Rijo You're welcome. If it helped you, you can upvote the answer and marked it as resolved.

Comment: can i return a value from `function printMessage() { return 'message'; }`